# Arduino variable usage

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm a newbie when it comes to Arduino and C++.

I'm trying to write a program that reads the input data from analog pin zero (a POT).
after the value is read I want it to print to the serial monitor, but only once. if the value of from analog pin zero changes I want it to print the new value to the serial monitor. I'm trying to use global variables, but to no avail. any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int entered=0;
int flag;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

int potValue=analogRead(A0);

if (!entered){
entered=1;
Serial.println(potValue);

}
int flag=potValue;

if (flag!=flag){
entered=0;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is really close.  This line is your mistake

```
int flag=potValue;
```

As written, that creates a new local variable *flag*.  The local variable hides the global variable.  So the comparison is always to itself and never fails.  Change the line to :

```
flag=potValue;
```

and your program will function as desired.

You can save some memory and code space like this:

```
int g_lastValue = 0;

void loop() {

  int nowValue = analogRead(A0);

  if (nowValue != g_lastValue) {
    Serial.println(nowValue);
    g_lastValue = nowValue;
  }
  ...
}
```

The use of g_ as name prefix is a cue that a variable is global.  I use this naming convention as it helps when reading a function to know variables that are not local.  Without a name cue, you need to scan the entire function body to see if there is a variable declaration present, and only by looking through the function and **not** finding a declaration can you know the variable must be global.  On small functions, not really an issue, but as your code grows, you may want some self documentation a naming convention provides.

Answer (score 1):

You're on your way but you are getting tangled a bit in variables.

It can be simpler: just one global variable and one conditional check.

```
int lastRead = -1; // init to value outside of possible range

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  // get current value
  int currentRead = analogRead(0);

  //compare and only print if !=
  if (currentRead != lastRead){
   lastRead = currentRead; // store
   Serial.println(lastRead);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried both of these and they both are not working as I thought they would. it still prints a ton of values, I was trying to come up with a way to only print the read value to the serial monitor only once.

Comment: @DustinAHenry - perhaps an issue with how you have it wired up? What are the values being printed? Same value over and over?

Comment: After running a quick test I believe I solved the problem. It appears that the pot value is "bouncing" around and that is why it continually is printing to the serial monitor. I need to write a denouncing function for the Analog read portion.

Comment: @DustinAHenry - welcome to the world of hardware debugging ;-)

Comment: So you are saying this falls in the category of "be careful what you wish for":)  The same number is never printed twice in a row, correct?  But now you have another question, "the input changes alot, how do I make it more stable?" For that, look to the electronics forum - a little cap and resistor can fix.  Or for a code solution look for rate limit and filtering.